# Recovering data after errant copy command?

Tags: linux, windows-xp, cygwin

I meant to do this:

```
cp -rp -i /cygdrive/c/folder /cygdrive/e/anotherfolder/
```

But I accidentally hit enter after this:

```
cp -p -i /cygdrive/c/folder /cygdrive/e/anotherfolder/
```

And now the contents of `~/Documents/anotherfolder/` is empty because `~/Documents/folder` was not a regular file (it was a directory). I'm surprised this was the outcome (contents of `anotherfolder` removed) and there was no error given.

Are the contents of `/cygdrive/e/anotherfolder/`? I would appreciate any advice... Thanks. (This is on cygwin running on Windows XP)

**EDIT** I think the data is still there, as the folder had about 1.5 TB of data and hard disk usage indicates that this data is not cleared off.

Comment: `cp` doesn't delete anything, it may overwrite a target if it exists already. As you specified the `-i` flag, no harm should be done.